# How much speed improvement does it run from 100 seconds to 80 seconds.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

Yes, I know, 20/100=20%, so there is 20% improvement if someone or something run the same distance or finish the same task from 100 seconds to 80 seconds.

However, recently I saw another argument says there should not be 20% but 40%, because from 100s to 50s, that's 100% improvement. 20s is 40% of 50s, so there is 40% improvement.

So where goes wrong?

Comment: It is a 25% improvement.  $\frac {100}{80} = 1.25$

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, neither result you stated is correct. Note speed and time are different things, with them being [inversely proportional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)#Inverse_proportionality) to each other (i.e., as one increases by a factor of $f$, the other decreases by a factor of $f$). For example, let's say the average speed is how fast an object moves a distance $d$. Using that speed is the distance divided by the time, i.e., $s = \frac{d}{t}$, this then gives

$$s_1 = \frac{d}{100} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$s_2 = \frac{d}{80} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

as the speeds before and after. The relative change, with a negative value meaning a decrease, when expressed as a percentage at the end, is given by

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
c & = \frac{s_2 - s_1}{s_1} \\
& = \frac{\frac{d}{80} - \frac{d}{100}}{\frac{d}{100}} \\
& = \frac{100}{80} - 1 \\
& = .25 \\
& = 25\%
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

This is what [Doug M](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/317162/doug-m)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834012/how-much-speed-improvement-does-it-run-from-100-seconds-to-80-seconds#comment7907581_3834012) also states.

The reason the other argument you saw also doesn't work is that it's assuming speed and time are [directly proportional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportionality_(mathematics)#Direct_proportionality) (i.e., as one increases by a factor of $f$, so does the other) but, as I stated earlier, they are actually inversely proportional instead.